# Translate Elasticsearch DSL to gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I've got json that I want to translate into an Elasticsearch query using https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5

json =

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "Videos.en"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Pretty simple!  What I've got so far - which clearly isn't working - is:

```
enVidsQuery, err := elastic.NewBoolQuery().
        Filter(elastic.Exists("field", "Videos.en"))
```

Where `elastic` references "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5" in my imports.

Can anyone provide me with the correct syntax?  I figure it's a trivial solution for anyone familiar with the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query will be:

```
elastic.NewBoolQuery().Filter(elastic.NewExistsQuery("Videos.en"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give this a try tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.  :)